# Hive on Hadoop, Map Reduce not working - Error: Could not find or load main class 1600

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

Need help in resolving below issue.
I have installed Ubuntu as Windows subsystem on Windows 10.
Installed Hadoop 3.1.3 and Hive 3.1.2

When I am running normal query without MapReduce its running fine.

```
hive> use bhudwh;
OK
Time taken: 1.075 seconds
hive> select id from matches where id < 5;
OK
1
2
3
4
Time taken: 6.012 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
hive>
```

When running MapReduce query, it throws error - Error: Could not find or load main class 1600.

```
hive> select distinct id from matches;
Query ID = bhush_20200529144705_62bc4f10-1604-453f-a90c-ed905c9c1fe9
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1590670326852_0003, Tracking URL = http://DESKTOP-EU9VK4S.localdomain:8088/proxy/application_1590670326852_0003/
Kill Command = /mnt/e/Study/Hadoop/hadoop-3.1.3/bin/mapred job  -kill job_1590670326852_0003
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2020-05-29 14:47:24,644 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2020-05-29 14:47:41,549 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_1590670326852_0003 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_1590670326852_0003_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1590670326852_0003
Task with the most failures(4):
-----
Task ID:
  task_1590670326852_0003_m_000000
URL:
  http://0.0.0.0:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1590670326852_0003&tipid=task_1590670326852_0003_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
[2020-05-29 14:47:40.355]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1590670326852_0003_01_000005
Exit code: 1
[2020-05-29 14:47:40.360]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class 1600
[2020-05-29 14:47:40.361]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class 1600
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
hive>
```

Below are few lines from Hadoop logs.

```
2020-05-29 14:47:28,262 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2020-05-29 14:47:28,262 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1590670326852_0003_m_000000_0: [2020-05-29 14:47:27.559]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1590670326852_0003_01_000002
Exit code: 1
[2020-05-29 14:47:27.565]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class 1600
[2020-05-29 14:47:27.566]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class 1600
```

I have tried all the configuration changes suggested in different threads but its not working.

I have also checked Hadoop MapReduce example of **WordCount** and it also fails with same error. 
All Hadoop processes seems running fine. Output of **jps** command.

```
9473 NodeManager
11798 Jps
9096 ResourceManager
8554 DataNode
8331 NameNode
8827 SecondaryNameNode
```

Please suggest how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the start command of the MapReduce task contains an illegal option `1600`. You need to check whether exists an illegal configuration `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts` with a value of 1600 in your yarn-site.xml.

Comment: Below is the value of tht parameter. `bhush@DESKTOP-EU9VK4S:~$ hdfs getconf -confkey yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts
-Xmx1024m`

Comment: You can also need to check the `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.admin-command-opts` and `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.profile.params` .